# Overwriting holder behavior with CSS when clicking on a link inside holder

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a gallery, and each item has the *.item* class. Inside the *.item* there is always a link to remove it:

```
<div class="item">Title of item <a href="#" class="remove">remove</a></div>
```

When you press on an .item, it displays a red border

```
div.item:active {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Now, my problem is that i do not want *.item* to display the red border if you press on the *.remove* link that is inside. How can i solve this issue? Is it feasible?

```
div.item:active a.remove:active {
    ???
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery solves this problem.
Use

```
$('a.remove').click(function(){
 $('div').removeClass("Classname");
});
```

[read this](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) reference

Comment: wait, but how do i only target the parent div to remove only that classname?

Answer (score 1):

Not with CSS only, as there is no way to target the parent with a CSS selector. Can you us javascript? Pretty easy with that.

Comment: thanks for the info. yes, i can javascript ;) hehe, i was just wondering if that was feasible with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.item:active a.remove:active {
    border:none;
}
```

should do the trick

EDIT- i didn't read the question properly.  You'll have to use javascript or something to accomplish what your after

Comment: No because that applies to the `a`.